# Replace first two digits of a value based on a condition in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with identifying codes, of which some are wrong by the first two digits (e.g., 3400808 instead of 3500808).

```
df <- as.data.frame(c(3400808, 3400809, 3400811))
```

I would like to replace the first two digits by 35 but keep the remaining five digits the same. Is there any function that would work here?

I would know how to replace the entire value but want to keep the last five digits (but also need the first two digits, so I cannot just drop them).

Answer (score 2):

This looks like division without remainder `%/%` and modulo `%%` would help you:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(3400808, 3400809, 3400811))

df$oldid <- df$id %/% 100000
df$remainder <- df$id %% 100000
df$newid <- 35*100000 + df$remainder

df
#>        id oldid remainder   newid
#> 1 3400808    34       808 3500808
#> 2 3400809    34       809 3500809
#> 3 3400811    34       811 3500811
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
numbers <- c(3400808, 3400809, 3400811, 42356)

3500000 + (numbers %% 100000)
# [1] 3500808 3500809 3500811 3542356
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
numbers <- c(3400808, 3400809, 3400811, 42356)

replace_start <- function(numbers, start, replacement) {
  stringr::str_replace(numbers, paste0("^", start), as.character(replacement)) |>
    as.numeric()
}

replace_start(numbers, 34, 35)
#> [1] 3500808 3500809 3500811   42356
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>